# Why am I suddenly getting "Compile Error: Constant Expression Required"?

Tags: excel, vba, constant-expression

I have the following code:

```
Private Enum dbi
        m = 0
        d = 1
        y = 2
        hh = 3
        mm = 4
        ss = 5
        ap = 6
        size = 7
End Enum

...

Sub CompileData()

    ...

    ReDim startEnd(deplCount * 2) As Date
    ReDim excludes(deplCount * 2) As Date
    ReDim hasExcls(deplCount) As Boolean

    ReDim deplLabels(deplCount) As MSForms.Label
    ReDim startLabels(deplCount) As MSForms.Label
    ReDim endLabels(deplCount) As MSForms.Label
    ReDim exclLabels(deplCount) As MSForms.Label
    ReDim exclChecks(deplCount) As MSForms.CheckBox

    ReDim mdyLabels(dbi.size * 2 * deplCount) As MSForms.Label

    ReDim dateGroup(dbi.size * 4 * deplCount) As MSForms.TextBox
    ReDim pctLabels(dbi.size * 4 * deplCount) As MSForms.Label

    Dim okButton As MSForms.CommandButton

    ...

End Sub
```

Note these two chunks lie in the same module, so even though the Enum is private, CompileData should still be able to access it.

I am ReDimming some arrays because I am not sure before the program launches how much data I am going to need to collect from this userform. This code has worked for a month, but now for some reason I am getting a constant expression compile error in the CompileData sub that specifically highlights "dbi.size." Are Enums suddenly not considered constant definitions? If I'm ReDimming, should it even matter?

Comment: [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13196909/2127508) suggests that this can be an intermittent error and that changing the enum to `Public Enum` or to just `Enum` can sometimes help

Comment: @barrowc Yep, after doing a little more experimenting that seems to be my issue as well. I guess I can remove the question as a duplicate?

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate. There's no need to delete the question. If it gets a few more duplicate votes then it will be automatically put on hold anyway

Comment: FWIW the linked OP mentions randomness as they haven't experienced the issue with or without a `Public` keyword - they seem to have missed the fact that `Public` is the implicit default in VBA. Also yes, `Enum` types are buggy in ways you can't even imagine, I have stories...

Answer (score 0):

After tooling around it appeared that all references to the Enum weren't working. I took off the "Private" handle and that has fixed the issue.