# Setting the Right Footer

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the Code:

```
Sub UpdateReport()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Puts in the effective date and member name

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Report As Variant
Dim xprating As Variant

Set Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Yearly Breakdown", "Loss Template", _
         "Codes", "Yearly Breakdown", "Cover Sheet", "Ag Loss Sensitivity", _
         "Experience Rating Sheet", "Loss Ratio Analysis", _
         "Mod Analysis&Strategy Proposal", "Mod Snapshot", _
         "Mod & Potential Savings"))

Set xprating = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Experience Rating Sheet")

For Each ws In Report
    ws.Calculate
Next ws

For Each ws In Report
    ws.Calculate
    ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = Sheet34.Range("B20").Text & Chr(10) & _
                      "Mod Effective Date:     " & Sheet17.Range("B4")
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Emod Report Updated!"

End Sub
```

I am getting a type mismatch error here:

`ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = Sheet34.Range("B20").Text & Chr(10) & "Mod Effective Date:     " & Sheet17.Range("B4")`

I didn't change anything at all it just happened.

Comment: What is the value of `Sheet34.Range("B20").Text`?

Comment: Its a string. but the weird part about this. is that it worked for weeks without this issue.

Comment: Can you Debug.Print that same string instead of assigning it to the footer?  Do you get the expected output?

Comment: Hi. I see no reason while it is not working. Something similar happened with my code. I found this [link]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196909/vba-enums-give-occasional-constant-expression-required-errors/20266136#20266136). It worked for me.